# PDO prepare with question marks doesn't work with numbers

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-like

I have this :

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');

$max = 10;
$min = 0;
$q = $_GET['q'];

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT ?, ?");
$result->execute(array('%'.$q.'%', $min, $max));
```

However it doesn't work (returns nothing) while when I replace LIMIT by LIMIT 0, 10 and remove $min and $max from the array it works.
What am I doing wrong? I tried using '0' instead of 0 but it doesn't work either...

Comment: [PDO prepared statement causes an error in LIMIT statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991623)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO::execute escapes all params as STRING.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');

$max = 10;
$min = 0;
$q = (isset($_GET['q']) && is_string($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : '';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT ?, ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%{$q}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $min    , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $max    , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the numbers are being binded as strings. From the manual:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters
>   in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as
>   PDO::PARAM_STR.

So you should use `bindValue` instead of the execute shortcut.